# Qual a funcionalidade do mainloop no frame do tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Eu estava tentando fazer um frame aparecer na tela no tkinter, e depois de muito, tentei checar a documentação e vi o nome "mainloop", ao testar ele aparecia na tela, o que eu não entendi, já que quando chamei por meio do pack ele não funcionou, só quando coloquei esse mainloop.

(PS: Chequei se era uma instância diferente do frame, mas era a do frame)

Por favor, alguém poderia me explicar o que esse mainloop do frame faz, porque nas docs do próprio tkinter é muito incompleto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O método `mainloop` é usado para **"travar" a execução da janela atual usando um event loop** do `tkinter`. Isso permite com que o `tkinter` possa disparar respostas a eventos na instância atual da janela que chamou o `mainloop`, como um *keypress* ou *click* e não permite a execução de códigos posteriores até que a janela seja fechada. Pode testar isso ao chamar o método `mainloop` com um código logo em seguida e verá que ele só será executado depois:

```
window = Tk()
window.mainloop() 
# esse print não será chamado até que feche a janela que chamou o método mainloop
print('chamou')
```

O `print` chamado só é executado quando a janela atual deixar o processo de `mainloop`, ou seja, tiver sua instância finalizada.